# Keycloak grant validation. Failed to load public key to verify token. Reason: socket hang up

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-connect

I'm using keycloak to protect an express API with the bearer-only authentication.

When the API is running locally I can request a token an use the services normally, but when it's running on a public IP I get the following error:

> grant error Grant validation failed. Reason: failed to load public key to verify token. Reason: socket hang up

I added these lines in the api middleware to get the error info:

```js
app.use((req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
  const token=req.headers.authorization.slice(7)
  keycloak.grantManager.createGrant({ 'access_token': token }).then(grant => {
    logger.info(grant)
  next()
  }).catch((error) => {
    logger.info("grant error", error)
    next()
  })
},keycloak.middleware());
```

What can be the reason for socket hang up only when it's not running locally?

Comment: are you using the same keycloak client config? can you connect from your server to the keycloak urls? maybe the network is blocking your request (outbound traffic). Try with curl

Comment: You're right! apparently network is blocking requests, I tried to send an axios request and same thing, socket hang up.